# Numpy Check if an element is in array

Tags: python, numpy, any

I have an array `c`, another array `d`. how can I check if `d[1]`or`d[3]`or`d[5]`or`d[7]` is in array `c`?

```
c = np.array([[ 1, 1,0],
              [ 1,-1,0],
              [-1, 1,0],
              [-1,-1,0]])
d = np.array([[2,2,2],
              [1,1,0],
              [2,8,8],
              [6,8,8],
              [2,2,2],
              [4,9,0],
              [2,2,2],
              [3,2,2]])
```

I tried  `g = np.any(c == d[1,3,5,7])` ,but it doesn't work. In this case, the result should be `True` because [1,1,0] is in array `c`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
# to check if a row in its entirety match a list, 
# use all on axis=1 first, then check if any rows match using any
(c==[2,1,0]).all(1).any()
False
```

For multiple checks

```
# use bit-wise | (instead of or)
((c==[2,1,0]) | (c==[3,1,0]) | (c==[5,5,0])).all(1).any()
```

Answer (score 4):

As you are using numpy use the function `isin` that is defined:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

```
g = np.isin([ 2, 1,0],c)
```

Edit: As @Phoenix suggested to make all the vector checking you need to add all at the end `g = np.isin([ 2, 1,0],c).all()` this return `False`. Tested in collab :

[image]

EDIT: you changed the question, but the answer is equally valid. Here it is how to check all d in c:
import numpy as np

```
c = np.array([[ 1, 1,0],
              [ 1,-1,0],
              [-1, 1,0],
              [-1,-1,0]])
d = np.array([[2,2,2],
              [1,1,0],
              [2,8,8],
              [6,8,8],
              [2,2,2],
              [4,9,0],
              [2,2,2],
              [3,2,2]])
for item in d:
  g = np.isin(item,c).all()
  print(g)
```

If you want a particular array in d use the formula without the for, just put d[0],d[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxKY8.png), etc.... instead of item.......
Google colab tested:

[image]

Comment: but this return me` [False True True] `,  what I want is only `False `.

Comment: @Kevin, You can add .all() at the end of your np.isin(), it works pretty well.

Comment: thx, updated my response to be more completed.

Comment: I don't think it can be used in this way. It will only judge whether each element of the first parameter is in the second element, and can't give whether the first parameter as a whole is one of the lines of the second parameter.

Comment: @MechanicPig it can be used, i added a screenshot in the answer with google colab. no problem there

Comment: @Kevin This is a counterexample: `np.isin([0, 3, 6], np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3))).all()`, as required by OP, it should output false because the first parameter as a whole is not one of lines of the second parameter, but the result is true.

Comment: In this case you are comparing a matrix to a vector, is not OP case. `isin` only checks if the numbers are the same, in this example: the matrix numbers are in the vector but is not apropiate to use `isin` at the whole matrix, you should check by columns or rows if is in interest. In any case to compare vectors of similar lenght is faster than doing `ìf`sentence. @MechanicPig

Comment: I think what OP wants is whether the vector is in the matrix, not each element. @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

The direct way should be to compare one by one:

```
any(any((i == j).all() for j in c) for i in d[1::2])
```

Or use one or two layers of Broadcasting:

```
any((c == i).all(-1).any() for i in d[1::2])
(c[:, None] == d[None, 1::2]).all(-1).any()
```

Using broadcast can calculate faster, but it must first calculate all the comparison results, and then check them with method `ndarray.any`, but loop check can reduce the number of comparisons.

In addition, `np.isin` can't meet your requirements. It only returns whether each element of first parameter is in the second parameter.